# How to make production build in grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I am newbie in **grafana**. How to i make production build in garfana and how can i push to production.

http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/
I am following above link to install grafana and build a development. But i dont know how to build a production. advance thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered  grafana docker  deployment ? http://docs.grafana.org/v4.3/installation/docker/

Comment: @SairamCherupally , The link provided above does not open up. I recently started exploring grafana 7.x, I could see few commands to create a build in grafana makefile(grafana/grafana/Makefile): <br/> npm run build. <br/> Should i use this or is there anything else i should be using to create a production build